# Spring OAuth2 Client dependency secures the application

Tags: java, spring-boot

The requirement is that my Spring Boot application (version 3.1.3) is functioning as a OAuth2 Client so that it can get an Access Token from the Authorization Server and eventually can talk to other OAuth2-secured endpoints. In order to achieve this I have added the following dependency:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

The problem is that by this dependency the Spring Security auto configuration takes place and my own Spring Boot application unexpectedly becomes OAuth2-secured but this is not what I want. My intention of the added dependency was only that I can receive the Access Token but not it intervenes into the application from which the client accesses an OAuth2-secured endpoint.

Any ideas how to disable this default behaviour (auto config) though allows my application to receive the Access Token from the Authorization Server? Might be the above dependency wrong for this use case?

Comment: You can disable spring security auto-configuration by using @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class }) annotation above your main class (which contain main method) Or by adding this configuration into the application.properties file: spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of excluding the Spring Security Auto Configuration (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration) which accounts for inconsistencies with the rest of the Spring Boot features (e.g. in conjunction with Spring Boot Actuator) all endpoints should be made open via the following Spring Bean:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint());
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll());
    return http.build();
}
```

This refers to: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.security